# Tethering won't work claiming data connection is unavailable

Tags: system-error, data-connection, wifi-tethering

When I try to turn on tethering/mobile hot spot it gives me the system message "Unable to connect, data connection not available." However it worked in the past with this carrier/phone and the internet still works. I can browse the web on my phone fine.

Things I tried so far:

- restarting my phone
- Taking it in and out of airplane mode
- turning wifi off and on
- turning on and off power saving
- turning sync on and off
- turning off high performance mode.
- resetting all network settings

Comment: Is your data connection turned on when you're trying to tether? If no, keep it turned on...

Comment: Yes. I have my data connection turned on. I tried turning it off and then on again also.

Answer (score 0):

I never did figure out what was causing this issue. I finally was able to fix the issue, though, by completely resetting the phone to factory settings and setting it up again.